# .NET on OSX (Mono): can't connect to MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb, macos, mono

I'm developing a restful service with Visual Studio for Mac. In order to connect to my local MongoDB instance (which is up and running), I installed the MongoDB NuGet package. Classes are referenced correctly into code, however once I try to perform a connection it responds with the following error:

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'BalanzaController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
  "StackTrace": "  at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, System.Type controllerType) [0x000f3] in <f99f496cb0d249c1a945c1fcabce1695>:0 \n  at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request) [0x00028] in <f99f496cb0d249c1a945c1fcabce1695>:0 \n  at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher+<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext () [0x000a9] in <f99f496cb0d249c1a945c1fcabce1695>:0 ",
  "InnerException": {
      "Message": "An error has occurred.",
      "ExceptionMessage": "ntdll.dll",
      "ExceptionType": "System.DllNotFoundException",
      "StackTrace": "  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Interop+NtDll:RtlGetVersion (Interop/NtDll/RTL_OSVERSIONINFOEX&)\n  at Interop+NtDll.RtlGetVersion () [0x0001a] in <f13660f89d0d419fba4e315693dd26ea>:0 \n  at System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.get_OSDescription () [0x00007] in <f13660f89d0d419fba4e315693dd26ea>:0 \n  at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.ClientDocumentHelper.CreateOSDocument () [0x00042] in <2c531fdd26874b5eb450bd126d409101>:0 \n  at System.Lazy`1[T].CreateValue () [0x00075] in /private/tmp/source-mono-4.8.0/bockbuild-mono-4.8.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/Lazy.cs:437 "
  }
}
```

It somehow fails at locating the correct dll file (or its correspondent in the Mono environment).

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: What's the full name of NuGet package you added? Not everyone can be used on Mono.

Comment: `MongoDB.Driver`, which is claimed to be official. This is what I get in `package.config`:
 <package id="MongoDB.Bson" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Driver" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="MongoDB.Driver.Core" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net45" />

Comment: Then your package.config is wrong. "net45" means .NET Framework 4.5 and above, which is Windows only. To use it on Mono, you have to change targetFramework to .NET Standard, http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/getting_started/installation/, and then also manually edit the csproj files to correct the referenced assemblies. NuGet might have thought Mono == .NET Framework, but it is not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For the sake of comprehension (I'm new in Mono), why is 4.5 non a valid framework? Is the same I have in web.config and on which my app regularly works.

Comment: I already said, Mono is NOT .NET Framework. I wouldn't waste more time on that.

Comment: @LexLi seemed to me to be reliable, as it was released from Microsoft itself. Do you have experiences on that?

Comment: @balanza did you solve that? I've got the same problem using a raspberry pi 3.

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact same exception on Raspberry PI 3 (ARMV7) using Mono JIT compiler version 4.6.2.
Downgrading the MongoDB C# drivers from 2.4.X to 2.3.0 solved the problem for me.

There is also an open issue here:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1875